# How to copy elements to next position, if it satisfies a certain condition in kotlin

Tags: string, list, kotlin, collections, split

I have a String say, `val statement = "Ramu is a genius-boy, who likes tea."`

Now, I convert this into list of words separated by space " " :

```
val ListOfString = ["Ramu", "is", "a", "genius-boy," "who", "likes", "tea."]
```

I want to know how do I copy "genius-boy", the number of times it contains "-"

so, final list should look like :

```
val listContainingConnectedWordCopies = ["Ramu", "is", "a", "genius-boy,", "genius-boy,", "who", "likes", "tea."]
```

even better would be this list

```
val listOfDisconnectedWords = ["Ramu", "is", "a", "genius,", "-boy,", "who", "likes", "tea."]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is to use `flatMap`, to map one element of the list to multiple elements.

For `listContainingConnectedWordCopies`, you can first count how many dashes there are, and generate a sequence containing one more copy than there are dashes. This is because when there are no dashes, you still want the word to appear in the resulting list *once*.

```
fun listContainingConnectedWordCopies(words: List<String>) =
    words.flatMap { word ->
        val dashCount = word.count { it == '-' }
        generateSequence { word }.take(dashCount + 1)
    }
```

For `listOfDisconnectedWords`, you can split each word by a regex that finds the index just before the dash, by using a lookahead. The result of this split is then used in a `flatMap`:

```
fun listOfDisconnectedWords(words: List<String>) =
    words.flatMap { it.split("(?=-)".toRegex()) }
```

Note that both of these solutions create new lists, rather than modify the existing list.